# NetCore Host.CreateDefaultBuilder doesn't get Development configurations

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm trying to create a background task within a console app.

But my host is not being configured correctly, it's saying i'm in production even if i've added an environment variable  `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":"Development"` on my machine.

I need this to get the UserSecrets added to the configuration while developping.
It's working in a WebProject but i need the same for the console app.

What am i doing wrong ?

Here is the code

```
    private static IHostBuilder CreateHost(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                // Here => there is no UserSecrets in the configurations.

                services.AddInfra(context.Configuration);
                services.AddAppCore();

                services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
            });
```

Comment: Any reason you are doing it in `HostBuilder` and not in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Startup is for WebServer or am i wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i was not reading too fast those documentation, i would have found it earlier...

```
WebServer = ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
Service = DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT
```

With the new environment variable DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT set to "Development" everything is fine!